# i have been struck on this conversion

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have to convert this from MySQL to PostgreSQL:

```
IF(
   IF(
      MT.SLIPTYPE=8,
      SUM(MT1.TOTAL),
      0-SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
   ) IS NULL,
   0.00,
   IF(
      MT.SLIPTYPE=8,
      SUM(MT1.TOTAL),
      0-SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
   )
) AS Totalcamp
```

to a `CASE` statement.  Can anyone help me?

I have tried like this, but it was not accepted:

```
case when MT.SLIPTYPE = 8 
    then
    case when sum(MT1.TOTAL) is null then 0.00 else sum(MT1.TOTAL) end
    else
    case when (0 - sum(MT1.TOTAL)) is null then 0.00 else (0-SUM(MT1.TOTAL)) end
end as TOTALSCHEME
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be straightforward:

```
CASE WHEN CASE WHEN MT.SLIPTYPE = 8
               THEN SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
               ELSE 0 - SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
          END IS NULL
     THEN 0.00
     ELSE CASE WHEN MT.SLIPTYPE = 8
               THEN SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
               ELSE 0 - SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
          END
END) AS Totalcamp
```

But it could be simplified considerably:

```
coalesce(
   CASE WHEN MT.SLIPTYPE = 8
        THEN SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
        ELSE 0 - SUM(MT1.TOTAL)
   END,
   0.0
)
```